# INNER JOIN inside Subquery SQL

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join

I'm having problem inserting inner join inside subquery like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,
    (DATEDIFF(day, Date, CurrentDate)) AS Age
    FROM Order_Member   
)sub
    WHERE Age > 7
```

Which in this case it produces output like this:

```
OrderID    Date     CurrentDate Quantity Total Age
 O01    2017-05-22  2017-05-31     3      150   9
 O02    2017-05-23  2017-05-31     2      160   8
```

Which is running correctly which only shows age > 7, but I cant put another table into the subquery using INNER JOIN. 
Any  Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can, just add an `inner join` clause to the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT    *,
              (DATEDIFF(day, Date, CurrentDate)) AS Age
    FROM       Order_Member om   
    INNER JOIN Other_Table ot on om.id = ot.id -- Here
)sub
    WHERE Age > 7
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN OrderWithMember  ON Order_Member.OrderID = OrderWithMember.OrderID`      It shows something like this: `Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 265
The column 'OrderID' was specified multiple times for 'sub'.`

Comment: @JoesLie you need to fully qualify the columns you're selecting

Comment: Yes, I already qualify with OrderID on both table, I dont get it

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your question and query I don't think even your require sub query

```
SELECT om.*, ot.*, (DATEDIFF(day, Date, CurrentDate)) Age
FROM Order_Member om
INNER JOIN  Other_Table ot on om.id = ot.id -- Here
WHERE  (DATEDIFF(day, Date, CurrentDate)) >7
```

A part from this you have other option like **Cross Apply**  as well.

Comment: But when I use your code I Produce duplication, where my other_table (OrderWithMember), produce O01 for M01, M02, M03, M04, M05. Instead of M01, which have configures fk earlier. But when I try using sub query, it not produce duplication

Answer (score -2):

u can use table1, table2 instead of sub